# Пул потоков. Не удаётся отменить задачу

Tags: java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте.

Есть программа, которую сам написал для создания и тестирования  пула потоков. Единственное, что осталось сделать, это добавить возможность отменять задачу по id, которая выполняется. Мой вариант почему-то ничего не отменяет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду признателен. Вот код пула:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public interface CustomQueue<E>{

public void enqueue(E e);

public E dequeue();

}
public class FreeThread extends Thread {
   private MyQueue<Callable> myQueue;
     public int task_count;
     public long seconds;
    public FreeThread(Worker worker,MyQueue<Callable> myQueue, String name) {

        this.myQueue = myQueue;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
        public void run() {

            while(true){
                try{

                Callable r = myQueue.dequeue();
                // print the dequeued item
              Date start=new Date();
                System.out.println(" Задачу принял поток : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() );
                task_count++;
                r.call();

                System.out.println(" Задачу выполнил поток :  " +      Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Date end=new Date();

                this.seconds = (end.getSeconds()-start.getSeconds());

                    }catch(Exception ex){}
            }
        }
}

public class MyQueue<E> implements CustomQueue<E>{

// queue backed by a linkedlist
private Queue<E> queue = new LinkedList<E>();

/**
 * Enqueue will add an object to this queue, and will notify any waiting
 * threads that now there is an object available.
 * 
 * In enqueue method we just adding the elements not caring of size,
 * we can even introduce some check of size here also.
 */
@Override
public synchronized void enqueue(E e) {

    queue.add(e);
    // Wake up anyone waiting on the queue to put some item.
    notifyAll();
}

/**
* Make a blocking call so that we will only return when the queue has
* something on it, otherwise wait until something is put on it.
*/
@Override
public synchronized E dequeue(){
    E e = null;

    while(queue.isEmpty()){
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    e = queue.remove();
    return e;
}
}

 public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
private FreeThread thread;
private int timelife;

 public MyTimerTask(FreeThread thread,int timelife)
 {
    this.thread=thread; 
    this.timelife=timelife;

 }
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void run() {

    if (thread.task_count<1){
     try {

        thread.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {}

    System.out.println(" Свободный поток : "+thread.getName()+" удален из пула в : "+new Date());
    }
    else{

        thread.task_count=0;
        MyTimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask(thread,timelife);

    Timer timer = new Timer(true);

    timer.schedule(timerTask,thread.seconds*1000);}
}

}
  public class Task implements Callable  {
      public Future<Void> future;
        public int id;
       public  int time ;
       Task(int timeout) { time = timeout;Random rn=new Random(); this.id= rn.nextInt((2000 - 1) + 1) + 1;}
       public void setFuture(Future<Void> future) {
           this.future = future;
       }

       public Integer call() throws Exception   {

                 System.out.println("Начало задачи  id:"+id);

                    Thread.sleep(time*1000);

              System.out.println("Конец задачи  id:"+id);
              return this.id;
        }

    }

public class Worker implements Runnable{
private volatile boolean stop = false; 
private MyQueue<Callable> myQueue;
private String name;

public Worker(MyQueue<Callable> myQueue, String name){
    this.myQueue = myQueue;
    this.name = name;
}
public void requestStop() {
    stop = true;
  }

@Override
public void run() {

    while(true){
        try{

        Callable r = myQueue.dequeue();

        System.out.println(" Задачу принял поток : Thread - " + this.name );
        r.call();

        System.out.println(" Задачу выполнил поток: Thread - " + this.name);

            }catch(Exception ex){}
    }

}
}

public class ThreadPoolManager {

 private final int THREADPOOL_CAPACITY;
 // Queue<String> greeting  = new QueueLinkedList<>();
 MyQueue<Callable> myQueue = new MyQueue<Callable>();
 private final int timelife;
public ThreadPoolManager(int capacity,int timeout){
    this.THREADPOOL_CAPACITY = capacity;
    this.timelife=timeout;
    initAllHotConsumers();
    initAllFreeConsumers();
}

private void initAllHotConsumers(){
    for(Integer i = 0; i < THREADPOOL_CAPACITY; i++){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Worker(myQueue, i.toString()));
        thread.setName("Thread - "+i.toString());
        thread.start();
    }
}
private void initAllFreeConsumers(){
    for(Integer i = THREADPOOL_CAPACITY; i < THREADPOOL_CAPACITY*2; i++){
        FreeThread thread = new FreeThread(new Worker(myQueue, i.toString()), myQueue, null);
       thread.setName("Thread - "+i.toString());

        thread.start();
       Date start=new Date();

       TimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask(thread,timelife);
        //running timer task as daemon thread
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.schedule(timerTask, timelife*1000);

    }
}

public Future<String> submitTask(Callable r){
    myQueue.enqueue(r);
    return null;
}

}
```

А это тестирующий класс:

```
public class TestPool {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException  {

    ArrayList<Future<String>> results = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
     Set<Future<Integer>> set = new HashSet<Future<Integer>>();
     boolean quit = false;
    int thread_num=Integer.parseInt(args[0]) ; 
    int timeout=Integer.parseInt(args[1]) ;
    StringBuilder resultStr = new StringBuilder();
    ThreadPoolManager poolManager = new ThreadPoolManager(thread_num,timeout);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Выберите: добавить задачу в пул - 1 \n удалить задачу по id  - 2\n  выход - 3");
 // возвращает истинну если с потока ввода можно считать целое число
  do{

  int choice = sc.nextInt();
  if (choice==1)
  {       
     System.out.println("Введите длительность задачи"); 
     int time = sc.nextInt();
     Callable task=new Task(time);
     poolManager.submitTask(task);
    FutureTask<String> task1 =
            new FutureTask<String>(task);

    results.add(task1);

  }

 if (choice==2)
  {

     System.out.println("Введите id задачи"); 
     int id = sc.nextInt();

    results.get(id).cancel(true);

  }
  if (choice ==3)
  {quit=true;}
  }while(!quit);

    }
}
```

Comment: не вижу, чтобы использовался метод interrupt() для прерывания задачи. Зато вижу deprecated методы в участке кода, где Вы работаете с потоками. Почитайте, пожалуйста про правильную работу с тредами. https://habrahabr.ru/post/133413/ - интересная статья про прерывание и остановку потоков. Вообще, неплохо бы именно interrupt'ить поток, а потом уже пытаться с ним сделать что-то злое. Правильно написанные задачи для потоков должны правильно реагировать на прерывания.